# Crystal Report XI: How to view the relationship in the Command

Tags: sql-server, oracle, crystal-reports

I have an old Crystal Report using Oracle database. I am migrating to SQL Server. Hence I wish to create a new report using SQL Server. The problem I have is trying to figure out the relationship between fields in the old Crystal Report.

**What I did**

I created a new report using the SQL Server and I dragged all the table that I will be using

[image: Table which I need]

But in the old report, I see Command instead of tables. **What are the differences?**

[image: Commands]

**Trying to achieve**

Most fields are related to POI_NO which is from Table A. How do I see the relationship in the old report and set up the query in the latest report? How do I link my fields to Table A?

When I tried to right click and browse data on fields in the old report, I only get the following
[image: POI]

To all gurus, please help, your help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your old Crystal Report is not binding directly to tables, and instead binds to a view or an object data source populated before the report is run?

> But in the old report, I see Command instead of tables. What are the
>   differences?

'Command' is just a name, like a table name, or a datasource name. It is not a Command.

Look at the code behind the report and post more details.

Comment: How does the code behind the report works if I am coding in ASP.net any example will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to find in your code where you initialize your report.    new ReportDocument();  it is possible to create a dummy dataSource, build the crystalReport around that, call an Oracle procedure that returns the data, bind the data to the report datasouce, and show the report. You have the code, i cannot help you more :D

Answer (score 0):

*Command* here is a SQL query object. You can edit it following this steps :

1- In the Selected Tables area of the Database Expert, select the command you want to edit.

2- Right-click the command and select Edit Command from the shortcut menu.